# Multi stage Dockerfile leads to running out of space

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

As my code (nodeJS-application) is changing more often than the (npm) dependencies do, I've tried to build something like a cache in my CI.

I'm using a multi-stage Dockerfile. In that I run npm install for all, and only, prod dependencies. Later they are copied to the final image so that it is much smaller. Great.

Also the build get super fast if no dependency has been changed.

However, over time the hd gets full so I have to run `docker prune ...` to get the space back. But, when I do this, the cache is gone.

So if I run a `prune` after each pipeline in my CI, I do not get the 'cache functionality' of the multi-stage Dockerfile.

```
### 1. Build
FROM node:10.13 AS build
WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY ./package*.json ./
COPY ./.babelrc ./

RUN npm set progress=false \
    && npm config set depth 0 \
    && npm install --only=production --silent \
    && cp -R node_modules prod_node_modules
RUN npm install --silent

COPY ./src ./src
RUN ./node_modules/.bin/babel ./src/ -d ./dist/ --copy-files

### 2. Run
FROM node:10.13-alpine
RUN apk --no-cache add --virtual \
      builds-deps \
      build-base \
      python
WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY --from=build /home/node/app/prod_node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=build /home/node/app/dist .

EXPOSE 3000
ENV NODE_ENV production
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

Comment: What is wrong with that question, as it is downvoted and there is a close request. It doesn't help, if there is no comment on that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your CI system lets you have multiple `docker build` steps, you could split this into two Dockerfiles.

```sh
# Dockerfile.dependencies
# docker build -f Dockerfile.dependencies -t me/dependencies .
FROM node:10.13
...
RUN npm install
```

```sh
# Dockerfile
# docker build -t me/application .
FROM me/dependencies:latest AS build
COPY ./src ./src
RUN ./node_modules/.bin/babel ./src/ -d ./dist/ --copy-files

FROM node:10.13-alpine
...
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

If you do this, then you can [delete unused images](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/) after each build:

```sh
docker image prune
```

The most recent build of the dependencies image will have a label, so it won't be "dangling" and won't appear in the image listing.  On each build its label will get "taken from" the previous build (if it changed) and so this sequence will clean up previous builds.  This will also delete the "build" images, though as you note if *anything* changed to trigger a build it will probably be in the `src` tree and so forcing a rebuild there is reasonable.

In this specific circumstance, just using the `latest` tag is appropriate.  If the final built images have some more unique tag (based on a version number or timestamp, say) and they're stacking up then you might need to do some more creative filtering of that image list to clean them up.

Comment: What is the difference between `docker images -f dangling=true -q | xargs docker rmi` and `docker images prune`?

Comment: Nothing.  But `docker images -q | xargs docker rmi` worked back in the ancient days (also when multiple Dockerfiles was the only way to do "multi-stage" image builds) and it's what I've internalized.  `docker image prune` would work just fine here.

Comment: I updated the answer to use `docker image prune` as shorter and easier.